# Threading Library for Multithreaded Windows Service

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, threadpool, scheduling

I'm looking for a good library, preferably in C#, which I can use in a windows service and it will handle all the multithreading functionality needed.

The service will run every x minutes, check a database for processes to call, and for each of them spawn a thread and run it.

Each thread should handle exceptions, logging and such.

Any suggestions?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this project
http://www.codeplex.com/smartthreadpool

Project Description

Smart Thread Pool is a thread pool written in C#. It is far more advanced than the .NET built-in thread pool.
Here is a list of the thread pool features:

- The number of threads dynamically changes according to the workload on the threads in the pool.
- Work items can return a value.
- A work item can be cancelled.
- The caller thread's context is used when the work item is executed (limited).
- Usage of minimum number of Win32 event handles, so the handle count of the application won't explode.
- The caller can wait for multiple or all the work items to complete.
- Work item can have a PostExecute callback, which is called as soon the work item is completed.
- The state object, that accompanies the work item, can be disposed automatically.
- Work item exceptions are sent back to the caller.
- Work items have priority.
- Work items group.
- The caller can suspend the start of a thread pool and work items group.
- Threads have priority.
- Can run COM objects that have single threaded apartment.
- Support Action and Func delegates.
- Support for WindowsCE (limited)
- The MaxThreads and MinThreads can be changed at run time.
- Cancel behavior is imporved.

Comment: Fahad,

This is exactly what I'm looking for.

I'll wait if someone lese has a better idea, otherwise I'll mark yours as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit tongue in cheek, but how about the .NET Framework?  The [`System.Threading`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.aspx) namespace has everything you need for this.

If you can use .NET 4, or the backport in the Rx Framework, the Task Parallel Library may make some of this a bit easier, as well, but even without that, the standard framework has everything you'd need.

Comment: Reed,

I'm looking for a complete solution, a code implementation that uses System.Threading.

No, I can't use 4.0 yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use the Rx Framework?  It includes a full backport of the Task Parallel library, which provides a huge amount of usability (much better than any third party lib I've seen, to date).

Answer (score 2):

If you need a scheduling library that has multi-threading support, I've used this before:  Quartz.NET

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Can you give me n example on how you used it please?

Comment: There's a good tutorial on the site, but you basically setup scheduling "triggers" (based on cron syntax) that determine when a job fires, then you associate specific jobs to the triggers.  The Quartz.NET "Scheduler" handles all of the timing for you, and invokes your jobs at the set times.  http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html

Comment: We used it to kick off periodic database queries, which turn caused other actions to fire.

Comment: Looks promising... I'll take a better look at it. It runs OK in Windows Server 2008.